# How do I get rid of these leftover flatpak files?

Tags: gnome-terminal, flatpak

I wanted to try out Tauon Music Box, so I installed the flatpak version, didn't quite like it so I removed it with the following: `flatpak uninstall com.github.taiko2k.tauonmb`
but when I search for it with: `locate tauon` I found these files:

```
/var/lib/flatpak/appstream/flathub/x86_64/7cbba18599d341ff2e031150b5ab4bec37c8dd2474b7d3421094c64f8f86fa1e/icons/128x128/com.github.taiko2k.tauonmb.png
/var/lib/flatpak/appstream/flathub/x86_64/7cbba18599d341ff2e031150b5ab4bec37c8dd2474b7d3421094c64f8f86fa1e/icons/64x64/com.github.taiko2k.tauonmb.png
/var/lib/flatpak/repo/refs/heads/deploy/app/com.github.taiko2k.tauonmb
/var/lib/flatpak/repo/refs/heads/deploy/app/com.github.taiko2k.tauonmb/x86_64
/var/lib/flatpak/repo/refs/heads/deploy/runtime/com.github.taiko2k.tauonmb.Locale
/var/lib/flatpak/repo/refs/heads/deploy/runtime/com.github.taiko2k.tauonmb.Locale/x86_64
/var/lib/flatpak/repo/refs/remotes/flathub/app/com.github.taiko2k.tauonmb
/var/lib/flatpak/repo/refs/remotes/flathub/app/com.github.taiko2k.tauonmb/x86_64
/var/lib/flatpak/repo/refs/remotes/flathub/runtime/com.github.taiko2k.tauonmb.Locale
/var/lib/flatpak/repo/refs/remotes/flathub/runtime/com.github.taiko2k.tauonmb.Locale/x86_64
```

How do I get rid of those?

Comment: How about deleting them? 

Comment: I know, but is there a "fancy" command that would delete them automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clean your flatpak installation with:

```
flatpak uninstall --unused
```

Add the `--delete-data` option to also remove user data for which no flatpak is installed anymore.
That will remove unused libraries, etc.

You can also check and repair your installation using

```
flatpak repair
```

This will remove invalid objects and reinstall where needed.

Comment: I got rid of some other files this way, but the tauonmb still remain untouched

Comment: That is the best I can give you. If uninstall scripts do not otherwise remove remaining directories or files, you may risk to delete them manually. If you break something, the `flatpak repair` command likely will allow you to make the system consistent again. Accept the better answer if it still arrives, but if there is nothing better, then please accept this answer.

Comment: Appreciate the help! I guess I'll delete them manually then.

Comment: The folder `/var/lib/flatpak/appstream/... ` contains icons for all flathub apps (seemingly all).  I think you can let this remain.  The files in `/varlib/flatpak/repo/.. ` that are not in use may be removed manually. I did that with lollypop music player and no problems yet.  I used  `uninstall --unused --delete-data` and `repair` before doing this.